# Reading a text file using Pandas accurately in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, txt

I am trying to read `B.txt` using `pandas`. It prints the value of `B` but not as a list. I present the current and expected outputs.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("B.txt", header=None)
B = df. to_numpy()
B=B.tolist()
print("B =",B)
```

The current output is

```
B = [['B=3']]
```

The expected output is

```
B=[3]
```

Comment: I think you should skip some lines for reading the file.

Comment: I skipped some lines but still I am not getting the expected output. I have updated the current output above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `squeeze = True` for `Series`, so ouput is `B = ['B=3']`, select first value and split, select second value and convert to int:

```
s  = pd.read_csv("B.txt", header=None, squeeze = True)
print (s)
0    B=3
Name: 0, dtype: object

print (s.iat[0])
B=3
print (s.iat[0].split('='))
['B', '3']

print (s.iat[0].split('=')[1])
3

print("B =", int(s.iat[0].split('=')[1]))
B = 3
```